# Rich Snippet is not Live? It's been 5 months now. What could be the reason

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

It's been 5 months that we have implemented Rich snippet on my website. But, the schema is not live. Can anybody please tell me what could be the reason for that. Please give me suggestions to modify it.

Comment: Individual website troubleshooting is considered off-topic here. There are quite a few questions related to why rich snippets might not be displayed, please use the Search function above to find them.